# How to get Property name from MethodCallExpression?

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm trying to call a method with an Expression, and return a string for building a sql query.

the call is simple

```
var actualUsers = db.Query<UserModel>( u => u.FirstName.Contains( "ues" ) && u.LastName == "" );
```

The in my evaluater, I'm able to get `"LastName = ''"` very easily, using a BinaryExpression evaluator.

However, when I try to get "FirstName" out of the `MethodCalLExpression`, the closest I can get is `u.FirstName` by using `expression.Object.ToString();`

What is the right way to get the property name of the MethodCallExpression?

Here's the method I've got so far.

```
    public static IList<TModel> Query<TModel> ( this IDbProvider iDbProvider, Expression<Func<TModel, object>> exp ) where TModel : class, new()
    {
        // SELECT * FROM [Users] WHERE FirstName LIKE '%ues%'
        // Should return the "Guest" user.

        var sqlExpression = GetSqlExpression( exp.Body );
        return // ....
    }

    private static string GetSqlExpression ( Expression expression )
    {
        if ( expression is MethodCallExpression )
        {
            return GetMethodCallOperator( ( MethodCallExpression )expression );
        }
        // more crap...
    }

    private static string GetMethodCallOperator ( MethodCallExpression expression )
    {
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda( expression.Arguments[0] );
        var compiledExpression = lambda.Compile().DynamicInvoke();


        var commandText = string.Empty;
        var key = expression.Object.ToString(); // "u.FirstName" -- should just be "FirstName"
        var value = compiledExpression.ToString(); // "ues"
        switch ( expression.Method.Name )
        {
            case "Contains":
                commandText = "[{0}] LIKE '%{1}%'";
                break;
        }

        // return "[FirstName] LIKE '%ues%'";
        return string.Format(commandText ,key, value);
    }
```

Comment: You should be visiting `expression.Object` to get that value using an `ExpressionVisitor`, to which you can support all possible values of the sub-expression rather than hard coding something that will only work in that very specific instance.

Comment: @Servy, I have never done anything like this and am sitting on a steep learning curve. I would love to figure out how wire up an ExpressionVisitor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example:

```
var memberAccess = expression.Object as MemberExpression;
Console.WriteLine(memberAccess.Member.Name); //will print FirstName
```

[MemberExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.memberexpression.aspx) is class, describing accessing a field or property. Use it to access property name. I assume, you pass parsed Expresssion like `u.FirstName.Contains( "ues" )` into `GetMethodCallOperator`

Full example:

```
void PrintName(Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> func)
{
    var methodCall = func.Body as MethodCallExpression;
    var property =  methodCall.Object as MemberExpression;
    Console.WriteLine (property.Member.Name);
}

PrintName(u => u.FirstName.Contains( "ues" )); //prints FirstName
```

where:

```
class Foo
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Of course, in a real query provider you should be visiting that expression through an expression visitor, not hard wiring in that exact layout.

Comment: @Servy could you please expand your comment? The question was `What is the right way to get the property name of the MethodCallExpression?`, I'm not pretending to solve all the problems, just an example of how to get property access name from `MethodCallExpression`. Maybe I'm missing something

Comment: Cool, it was the `MemberExpression` bit that I was missing.

Comment: The OP is trying to write a query provider.  This works for the single example that the OP is using, but won't work for other types of expressions that can be used.  Doing this is fine for a "hello world" of query providers, but not really beyond it.

Comment: @Servy completely agree.

Comment: If I have `i => i.CaseHandlers.Select(ch => ch.Office)` or even a longer expression (I will use this for **EntityFramework** *Include* method) and want to get the rightmost part, i.e. property - Object is null. So the only thing is available is last argument for MethodCallExpression, right?